# Data Model for user status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My table has the following attributes with **P_UserID** as the Primary key.

|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|

| **P_UserID**| P_TimeStamp | Date | P_Status|

P_Status is the user status at the given point of time. so here basically i am just logging the user activity that was accessing the application.

Now here are my access patterns that i want from DynamoDB.

1. Get all the available users who are online.
2. Get the user activity during the period of time. Lets say for example how many times does an user has come online in particular day.

Is it possible to have these kind of access patterns with the given table structure..? Or i am missing something about dynamodb..?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to remember about DynamoDB 'tables' :

1. Every record in a 'table' doesn't need to have the same structure
2. Every incoming data point does not need to correspond to only one record; it could result in multiple insertions / updates in the table

With these points in mind, we can try designing the table to answer the two questions as follows :

1. "Get the user activity during the period of time. Lets say for example how many times does an user has come online in particular day"

For this, consider a record like this:

```
{
  pk : <P_UserID>,   // partition key
  sk : <P_TimeStamp> // range key,
  current_status : <P_Status>,
  timestamp : <P_Timestamp>
}
```

For any user, you can retrieve activity in a time range using something like `pk = <user id> and sk BETWEEN <timestamp 1> and <timestamp 2>`. This is because range keys in DynamoDB support key comparisons such as [starts with, between, >, <, etc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html)

2. "Get all the available users who are online"

For this, whenever a user event comes into the system, insert a record that looks like this :

```
{
  pk : <P_UserID>,         // partition key
  sk : "CURRENT_STATUS",   // hardcoded string
  current_status : <P_Status>,
  timestamp : <P_Timestamp>
}
```

Since every insert for a given user has the same secondary key, new values will overwrite the old ones and the `current_status` property remains updated with the latest value received by the system.

This does not, however allow you to retrieve all users with status 'ACTIVE'

For that you need to create a [global secondary index (GSI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) which looks like this :

```
{ 
 gsi_pk : <current_status>,   // GSI partition key 
}
```

All key fields of the original table are copied to the GSI by default, so the userIDs are available on the GSI by default.

Now, getting all users with status 'ACTIVE' can be achieved with this query on the GSI : `gsi_pk = "ACTIVE"`

Comment: Thank you!! This has almost solved my both the access patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve this problem.(Credits go to a linkedin talk, I saw some time back, whose link I am not able to find).

We need to track and store user status. It could be anything like availability, status etc.

For now lets take example of availability status (the green dot we all are fond of)

Client need to keep sending pings every x seconds when user is available (Let's say x=10 seconds). Every time a new ping comes we schedule a new event which will get triggered after y seconds (y>x). We have 2 listeners,

1. Listening to the ping.

   It will create a new row in the datastore marking availability and create a new event which will trigger after y seconds.
2. Listening to event

   It will check if any new event has come in last z seconds. If No, create a new row in datastore marking not availability otherwise do nothing.

Simplistic example

```
x=10 second, y=30 seconds, z=20 seconds.

t=0: available ping, schedule an event for 30 seconds.

t=10: available ping, schedule an event for 30 seconds.

t=20: user went offline, so no update

t=30: event trigger, no activity since user ping is there at t=10

t=40: event trigger, mark user as offline.
```

As a result of above application we will have entries like below in datastore

```
id    timestamp status
usr1   0         available
usr1   10         available
usr1   20         available
usr1   40         offline

usr1   100        available
usr1   110        available
usr1   130        offline
```

Now you can solve your 2 access patterns.

**Note**: The solution is agnostic of any datastore.